# I have to convert English filename to some other international language using java

Tags: java, excel, file, zip

I'm facing an issue while encoding the zip file name into UTF-8. This is my code.

```
String filename1=URLEncoder.encode(fileName,"UTF-8");
```

`"fileName"` is the name of the zip file name. Please anyone can help me.

Comment: You may probably need to use `UTF-16` encoding.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Is there any (error) output? Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifyable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Well, you should definitely use UTF-8, not any other encoding.  Can you give us an example of the file name that you're trying to encode, the result that your code is giving, and the result that you were expecting; so that we can understand your problem?